# Deserialize XML using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have the follwoing XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SERVICES.OUTPUTResponse>
  <Results>
    <Result>
      <Dataset name="OutputData">
        <Row>
            <country>USA</country>
            <pubyear>9986</pubyear>       
            <numart>123</numart>
            <numcites>456</numcites>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <country>USA</country>
            <pubyear>97</pubyear>
            <numart>895</numart>
            <numcites>231</numcites>
        </Row>
      </Dataset>
      <Dataset name="Result 2">
        <Row>
          <Result_2>
            true
          </Result_2>
        </Row>      
      </Dataset>
    </Result>
  </Results>
  <_Probe></_Probe>
</SERVICES.OUTPUTResponse>
```

and i tried to deserialize by using XmlSerializer but it returns null.

The Property class which i used is

> public class XMLDetails
>       {
>
> ```
>     public string country { get; set; }
>
>     public string pubyear { get; set; }
>
>     public string numart { get; set; }
>
>     public string numcites { get; set; }
> }
> ```

**Deserialize  code is**

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = "SERVICES.OUTPUTResponse";   
                                xRoot.IsNullable = true;
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDetails), xRoot);
                var reader = new StringReader(remoteXml);
var objpublication = (XMLDetails)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
```

Please help me to reslove it

Comment: Is it a requirement to deserialize into the XMLDetails object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Linq To Xml

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or XDocument.Load(filename);

var rows = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Dataset[@name='OutputData']")
            .Descendants("Row")
            .Select(r => new XMLDetails
            {
                country = r.Element("country").Value,
                pubyear = r.Element("pubyear").Value,
                numart = r.Element("numart").Value,
                numcites = r.Element("numcites").Value,
            })
            .ToList();
```

PS: required namespaces `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Xml.XPath`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `xsd.exe` for generating `.xsd` (schema) file and `.cs` (class) file

[XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can run **"Visual Studio Command Prompt"** and xsd.exe path definition is already defined it is ready to use.

Type the following command in the console 
*I assume your xml is saved in **"yourxmlfile.xml"**

`>xsd.exe yourxmlfile.xml`

this command will generate **"yourxmlfile.xsd"** file

then execute the following command for generating `.cs` file
But before change the

`<xs:element name="Results" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">` line with
`<xs:element name="Results" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">` in generated xsd file
(to change Results to property instead of array propery)

`>xsd.exe yourxmlfile.xsd /c`

this command will generate **"yourxmlfile.cs"**

now you can add this file to your project and you can deserialize xml file as below

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SERVICESOUTPUTResponse));
        SERVICESOUTPUTResponse instance = null;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\path_to\yourxmlfile.xml"))
        {
            instance = (SERVICESOUTPUTResponse)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
```